# Bluetooth Firmware Problem

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I got ubuntu 16.04 and my Bluetooth is not working. 
I will give you the steps I have done so far.

1)`$ lsusb | grep Blue`

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0

2)
Downloaded the .hcd file from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm and pasted to `/lib/firmware/brcm` with name `BCM.hcd`

3)
restarted, Still no luck.

4)`$ dmesg | grep Blue`

> [    9.609647] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
>
> [    9.609665] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager
>   initialized
>
> [    9.609669] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
>
> [    9.609671] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
>
> [    9.609677] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
>
> [    9.937978] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
>
> [    9.938983] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
>
> [    9.954988] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
>
> [    9.954992] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
>
> [   12.028141] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0a0a tx timeout
>
> [   13.415325] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
>
> [   13.415326] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
>
> [   13.415331] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
>
> [   20.188041] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
>
> [   22.300055] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
>
> [   30.428134] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed
>   (-110)
>
> [   32.572135] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
>
> [   40.668143] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed
>   (-110)

So what's next, read everything available online, I am completely stuck

My laptop : Dell Inspiron 15R 3521

*Wifi is working fine.

Comment: Totally shut the computer down, then boot

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, not working.